# Databinding to object - howto update object/binding?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I got a textbox and use databinding to an object. This works fine, until I try to select a new product:

```
product = new Product(id);
textbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", product, "ProductName");

// After user action:
product = new Product(newId); // <- the textbox isn't updated
```

Do I have to clear the databinding and set it again after the product is updated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short: Yes, you have to re-establish the DataBinding, cause the TextBox has a reference to the old object.

But to make this a little more robust, you should maybe use a BindingSource for your DataBinding. To get this to work, you should open your form in design view.

- Select your TextBox and open the Properties window
- Look into category **Data** and click on the cross to the left of the **(DataBindings)** property
- Click on the drop down button next to the **Text** property
- In the drop down list select **Add project data source**
- From the wizard select **Object** and in the next your object type

Now you'll get a new object in your form (e.g. *productBindingSource*), that is bound to the text of your TextBox. Last but not least you have to attach your object by using the following code:

```
productBindingSource.DataSource = product;
```

But also this solution doesn't help against a re-binding, but all you have to do now is:

```
product = new Product();
productBindingSource.DataSource = product;
```